# Get specific data from first JsonArray

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I'm trying to get data from an API that returns data in the format:

```
[{
    "song": {
        "id": 12345,
        "track": "TRACK A",
        "artist": "ARTIST A"
    },
    "playedtime": "2018-02-14T09:07:15.976"
}, {
    "song": {
        "id": 54321,
        "track": "TRACK B",
        "artist": "ARTIST B"
    },
    "playedtime": "2018-02-14T09:03:29.355"
}]
```

I need to get only the first `track` and `artist` entry, which in the above example is "TRACK A" and "ARTIST A".

What I've done so far which is probably really wrong is:

```
string response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
JArray parser = JArray.Parse(response);
rootTrack = JObject.Parse(parser.First.ToString())["track"].ToString();
rootArtist = JObject.Parse(parser.First.ToString())["artist"].ToString();
```

Comment: the json isnt valid.

Comment: @MichaelRandall my bad, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend creating a c# representation of your data as follows:

```
public class Song
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("track")]
    public string Track { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("artist")]
    public string Artist { get; set; }
}

public class PlayListItem
{
    [JsonProperty("song")]
    public Song Song { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("playedtime")]
    public DateTime PlayedTime { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use JSON.net to deserialize your JSON data and access the required properties as follows:

```
List<PlayListItem> playList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PlayListItem>>(response);

PlayListItem firstItem = playList.First();
string track = firstItem.Song.Track;
string artist = firstItem.Song.Artist;
```